# socket conneted using localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby, sockets

i have the following code

```
require 'socket'


def connect(socket)
  while line = socket.gets # Read lines from socket
    puts line         # and print them
  end
  socket.close             # close socket when done

end

def serve(server)
  loop do
    client = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
    client.puts "Hello !"
    client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
    client.close
  end
end


if ARGV[0] == "-s"
  ip_port = ARGV[1]
  server = TCPServer.new  ip_port
  serve(server)
elsif ARGV.length == 2
  ip_address = ARGV[0]
  ip_port = ARGV[1]
  puts ip_address
  puts ip_port
  socket = TCPSocket.new ip_address , ip_port
  connect(socket)
else
  puts "PLease enter an IP address and IP port"
end
```

The code above is a basic server and client. use the -s flag to tell the program to act like a server.

This code works when I use localhost as a address but does not work when I use 127.0.0.1 as the address. I receive a `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)` error when i use 127.0.0.1. was wondering if anyone knows what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code itself, this looks like more of an issue due to firewall settings or perhaps something else on the machine.

You could always try opening the port and then attempting to telnet into it from a different terminal `telnet 127.0.0.1 port`. You can also use `netstat -atun` to check if the port is indeed open and to which address it is bound (0.0.0.0 means accessible by all IP addresses).

Comment: so after looking at netstat i fingered out that TCPServer uses ipv6. thanks for the tip